# How to start nvidia driver in console?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, drivers

I've downloaded and installed latest NVIDIA driver from [nvidia.com](http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux_display_ia32_185.18.31.html). Video card works silently in X session. But when I work in console without starting X, video card fan makes a lot of noise. Seems to be that NVIDIA driver (which manage fan speed) is not loaded during system boot. Is it possible to start the driver during boot?

**UPD:** While in console **`lsmod | grep nvidia`** shows that driver is loaded. Seems to be it is not loading issue. Video card fan has speed 100% in console, and 65.1% in X session. Is there way to change fan speed in console?

Answer (score 4):

Is the `nvidia` kernel module loaded?

```
lsmod | grep nvidia
```

If not, load it with

```
sudo modprobe nvidia
```

If it helps then you might want to automatically load it at boot time by appending nvidia (on a new line) to `/etc/modules`

I guess that source of your problem is manual installation. Had you installed it from repositories, the installer would set it up for you.

*Note: I am not an nvidia user, quick google search suggests that the module is called nvidia, but it might be called otherwise. Just type `modprobe n` and hit TAB, your shell should autocomplete the name for you.*

Answer (score 0):

I found this, you might wanna give it a try:

http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/adjust-fan-speed-you-nvida-graphics-card

there seems to be a command called nvclock, and within that command there is an argument called fanspeed. This is probably what your looking for.